# Using query results in a list from one class to another in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am retrieving data from a database in a class. I want to use that data and process it, separate into different sections (I have timestamps, and will count the frequency of names in between specific dates). I am having trouble finding out how to use the data I retrieved in another class. Here is my source code for the retrieval:

```
    package test;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
//import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
//import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;
import javax.sql.rowset.RowSetProvider;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

public class EnterD {

private static String url = "url";
private static String user = "user";
private static String password = "pass" ;

private static String sqlQuery1 = "SELECT component_type, ctime FROM table;";

public static List<MyDataType> retrieveFromDB() throws SQLException {
    List<MyDataType> dataList = new  ArrayList<>();
    try (Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)) {
        try (Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement()) {
            try (CachedRowSet crs = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet(); ) {
                crs.setCommand(sqlQuery1);
                crs.execute(conn);
                conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                while(crs.next()){
                    MyDataType dataType = new MyDataType();
                    dataType.setCpnType(crs.getString(1));
                    dataType.setCpnTimestamp(crs.getTimestamp(2));
                    dataList.add(dataType);         
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }       
    return dataList;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    retrieveFromDB();
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I am having trouble running the data in another class and retrieving it." Are you getting some exception? Or no data?

Comment: I am getting the data in the class when I run it, and I can check by using system.out to see each piece. But I don't know how to access the list I created in that class from another, and use the information. I clarified what I meant with an edit.

Comment: Assuming that you want this list in your `Main` function. Use `List<MyDataType> dataList = retrieveFromDB();` and then use this dataList as you want.

Comment: Thanks for that. If I wanted it out of the main function, do I simply define a new function and call that in the main?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can create another function which will call your retrieveFromDB() and process the output with some logic and that function can be called from your Main function.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you need to process the list on your main method then just create a List variable like this: `List<MyDataType> listOfElements = retrieveFromDB();`.
2. If you need to process the list but in some other class then go to your test package and create a new class, for example `MyListHandler`
3. Create an attribute in MyListHandler of type List like this: `List<MyDataType> myList;`
4. Create the constructor for MyListHandler

`public MyListHandler(List<MyDataType> myList){
        this.myList = myList;
    }`

5. Create some methods to work with the List in MyListHandler
   ]
   Methods:

   public void printList(){
           for (MyDataType item: myList) {
               System.out.println(item);
           }
       }

   ```
   public void clearList(){
       System.out.println("My list size: " + myList.size());
       myList.clear();
       System.out.println("My list size after clear: " + myList.size());
   }
   ```
6. Finally instantiate the MyListHandler in main method:

EnterD class:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        List<MyDataType> listOfElements = retrieveFromDB();
        MyListHandler myListHandler = new MyListHandler(listOfElements);
        myListHandler.printList();
        myListHandler.clearList();
    }
```

See the following complete example of MyListHandler:

MyListHandler.class

```
public class MyListHandler {

    List<MyDataType> myList;
    public MyListHandler(List<MyDataType> myList){
        this.myList = myList;
    }

    public void printList(){
        for (MyDataType item: myList) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }

    public void clearList(){
        System.out.println("My list size: " + myList.size());
        myList.clear();
        System.out.println("My list size after clear: " + myList.size());
    }

}
```

Regards.